# Could I archive object in `applicationWillTerminate:`?

Tags: ios, swift

As we know, when `app` will be killed, in `AppDelegate`, system will call `applicationWillTerminate:` method.

But you know, if the `archive` a `singleton`, it is a very import thing, and also if there is a `fetch data` action, will the `app` have been killed while the `network` or `archive` not finish yet?

Could I `archive` a `singleton` in the `applicationWillTerminate:` method?

The `applicationWillTerminate:` method:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate):

> Your implementation of this method has approximately **five** seconds to perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.

Given this information, if you are sure you can retrieve some information from a network and archive your object in probably less than 5 seconds, then yes you can do it in that method.

*Personally, I wouldn't do that in there as you are totally bound to the quality of your internet connection which can easily cause your network request to take more than 5 seconds.*

Comment: thanks, I also think there is a not good place to do these things, because if `device` out of power, this is also a possible reason.